# How to remove old session from Azure Storage Explorer?

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, import

Several months ago I experimented with importing Outlook PST files using the AZCopy tool and Azure Storage Explorer. I created an SAS URL within the Office 365 admin center which has since expired.

Instructions seen here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-network-upload-to-import-your-organization-s-PST-files-to-Office-365-103f940c-0468-4e1a-b527-cc8ad13a5ea6#step4

I've now returned to doing a production import of organization wide PST files and have gone through the process again. I've created a new SAS URL, and after uploading some test data with AZCopy I'm trying to add the storage endpoint in to Azure Storage Explorer.

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message when I try to add the new SAS URI: **A service connection with label 'ingestiondata' already exists.**

All import SAS URI's created in Office 365 admin center use "ingestiondata" as the resource label. So, my new SAS URI has the same label as the old one. I strongly suspect Storage Explorer is remembering the old one. Yet, as with much of the half-baked products Microsoft is shipping out in recent history, there isn't a single option anywhere within Azure Storage Explorer to REMOVE old SAS endpoints.

Uninstalling and reinstalling Azure Storage Explorer does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to clear out the old application data in %AppData%.

- Close all instances of Azure Storage Explorer.
- Open File Explorer and navigate to %AppData% (i.e.
  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming`)
- Locate the folder named `StorageExplorer` and rename it to
  `StorageExplorer.bak`

Re-open Azure Storage Explorer and it will have "forgotten" all the previous connections. One can only hope that someday Microsoft will think about adding a "remove" button.

Answer (score 1):

As per Step 3, sub-step 6 in this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-network-upload-to-import-your-organization-s-pst-files-to-office-365-103f940c-0468-4e1a-b527-cc8ad13a5ea6#step3 article you can/should detach from the Bloc Container when you are done with storage explorer. This will prevent the issue.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Please do not post link only answers. This is to prevent answers that are not longer helpful if the link gets broken. Relevant information should be included in your post. Thanks!